# Populate table with many intervals

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, data-warehouse

I have to populate these table with time internals:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[D_TIME_test](
    [DTMINUTES1] [datetime] NULL,
    [DTMINUTES5] [datetime] NULL,
    [DTMINUTES15] [datetime] NULL,
    [DTMINUTES30] [datetime] NULL,
    [DTMINUTES60] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

So I need table like this:

[image]

For one column I used:

```
DECLARE @start DATETIME, @end DATETIME  

SET @start = '20120901';
SET @end = '20170101'; 

WHILE @start < @end
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO D_TIME_test
  VALUES (@start)

  SET @start = DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, @start)
END
```

How to change this query to fill upper table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute your script first then update the other column with

```
UPDATE D_TIME_test SET
  DTMINUTES5 = DATEADD(mi, (DATEDIFF(mi, 0, DTMINUTES1) / 5) * 5, 0)
, DTMINUTES15 = DATEADD(mi, (DATEDIFF(mi, 0, DTMINUTES1) / 15) * 15, 0)
, DTMINUTES30 = DATEADD(mi, (DATEDIFF(mi, 0, DTMINUTES1) / 30) * 30, 0)
, DTMINUTES60 = DATEADD(mi, (DATEDIFF(mi, 0, DTMINUTES1) / 60) * 60, 0)
```

or you can edit your script adding the other columns

```
DECLARE @start DATETIME, @end DATETIME  

SET @start = '20120901';
SET @end = '20170101'; 

WHILE @start < @end
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO D_TIME_test
  VALUES (@start
        , DATEADD(mi, (DATEDIFF(mi, 0, @start) / 5) * 5, 0)
        , DATEADD(mi, (DATEDIFF(mi, 0, @start) / 15) * 15, 0)
        , DATEADD(mi, (DATEDIFF(mi, 0, @start) / 30) * 30, 0)
        , DATEADD(mi, (DATEDIFF(mi, 0, @start) / 60) * 60, 0)
         )

  SET @start = DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, @start)
END
```

`DATEADD(mi, (DATEDIFF(mi, 0, @start) / 60) * 60, 0)` takes the difference in minutes between a fixed value, in this case 0, and `@start` and add it back to the same value after taking away the remainder of the division by 60

In SQL Server if both part of a division are of integer type the result is also of an integer type, so there is no need to use `FLOOR`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
DECLARE @start DATETIME, @end DATETIME  

SET @start = '20151231 10:00';
SET @end = '20151231 15:00'; 

DECLARE @result_tbl TABLE(DTMINUTES1 DATETIME,
                          DTMINUTES5 DATETIME,
                          DTMINUTES15 DATETIME,
                          DTMINUTES30 DATETIME,
                          DTMINUTES60 DATETIME)

WHILE @start < @end
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @result_tbl(DTMINUTES1, DTMINUTES5, DTMINUTES15, DTMINUTES30, DTMINUTES60)
  VALUES(@start, 
         DATEADD(mi, 
                 - DATEPART(mi, @start) % 5,
                 @start),
         DATEADD(mi, 
                 - DATEPART(mi, @start) % 15,
                 @start),
         DATEADD(mi, 
                 - DATEPART(mi, @start) % 30,
                 @start),
         DATEADD(mi, 
                 - DATEPART(mi, @start) % 60,
                 @start))

  SET @start = DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, @start)
END

SELECT * FROM @result_tbl
```